# How do I split a string into an array of characters in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I want a user to input a word like `hello` and I want to split the word into an array of individual characters, like `["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]`.

I've already tried the `String#split()` method, but I don't know what argument to use to split each letter.

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "Hello";
char[] s_splitted = s.toCharArray();
```

Outputs an array with H as the first value, e as the second, etc.

Comment: The OP said he's trying to get a `String[]`, not a `char[]`.

Comment: Where does (s)he say that?

Comment: Where he said `I want the outcome to be in an array like "h" "e" "l" "l" "o".`, A `char[]` would hold `'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'` instead.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, it's best to add an explanation as well.

Comment: He's also been trying to get `split()` to work, which [returns a `String[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).